# How to create/declare secondary index in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

What is the sintaxis that I can use to create a secondary index in a MySQL table on any of its columns?

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-clustered indexes, will want to use something like:

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_{name}` ON `{TableName}` (`{column}`, `{column}`);
```

Be sure to change the items in squiggly brackets to something that is better suited to your goals.